# Insert data into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, mapping, data-warehouse, dimension

I have data like this

`MAPPING` table1:

```
ID1   NAME1 
-----------
001     1
002     2
```

`DATA` table:

```
TID_1   TNAME_1
------------------
1       ABCNAME
2       DEFNAME
```

Another `MAPPING` table2:

```
ID2   NAME2
--------------
001    1
002    2
```

`DATA` table:

```
TC_ID2  TC_NAME2
-----------------    
  1     C_NAME
  2     D_NAME
```

Here mapping tables are in database2 and data table are in databaes1
now I have another `dimension_location` table in database2 like this

```
ID1  NAME1    ID2   NAME2
-------------------------
```

I want to insert into this table like this

```
ID1  NAME1    ID2      NAME2
--------------------------------
001  ABCNAME  001001   C_NAME
002  DEFNAME  002002   D_NAME
```

Means I want to select name from database1 data table and for id I want to select from mapping table here in "**ID2**" column **001001** because **001** is for ID1 and another **001** is for ID2 so i combine those id and insert in id2 column how can I do this?

```
 insert into Dimension_location(ID1,Name1,ID2, Name2)
select dm.ID1,dv.TNAME_1,dmp.ID2,ds.TC_NAME2from 

ba.dbo.Mappingtable1 dm , 
ba.dbo.Mappingtable2 dmp

inner join Cen.dbo.datatable1 dv on dm.ID1=dv.TID_1   
inner join Cen.dbo.datatable2 ds on ds.ID2=dmp.TC_ID2
```

now how i combine id1 code with id2 code?

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Fully Qualified Names](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx) in order to write your query.  For example:

> database_name.schema_name.object_name.column_name

It will be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [database1].[dbo].[MAPPING TABLE] A
INNER JOIN [database2].[dbo].[DATA TABLE1] B
   ON A.[] = B.[]
...
```

Comment: yes but how i combine ID1 with ID2 and insert that id in ID2? this is actual problem

Comment: @What's the issue? Just join the corresponding tables.